# JMeter, encoding all parameters

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm looking for some advice on encoding in JMeter. I am currently working on a system that uses https and .aspx urls, and therefore need to encode all parameters within my post requests.As it stands i am copying and pasting web-forms from Fiddler to generate my test scripts. Is there a less labour intensive way to encode all my parameters of the web-form, because i am having to tick to encode each individual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most probably you are doing something weird, given you record your requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter should populate request parameters on its own including parameters values encoding if required. Check out [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) for details on how to perform recording of your test scenarios.
2. JMeter .jmx scripts are basically [XML files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) so you should be able to open JMeter script in your favourite text editor, locate the following line:

   ```
   <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
   ```

   and replace it with

   ```
   <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">true</boolProp>
   ```
3. You can substitute non-encoded parameters with their encoded equivalents using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code:

   ```
   org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments args = sampler.getArguments()
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   args.each {
       sampler.addEncodedArgument(it.getName(), it.getValue())
   }
   ```

   The above code will amend all the samplers in [JSR223 PreProcessor's scope](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) and substitute parameters values with their encoded equivalents. This approach can be resource intensive so use it wisely and if there is a possibility consider alternatives described in points 1 and/or 2. Just in case see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) to get familiarized with the concept of Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.